# Rerouting IP address or better solution on KVM on RHEL

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, vpn, kvm-switch

I've been having some issues accessing some secure websites through my KVM Windows 7 on a Linux RHEL. I have to use a VPN in the Windows 7 but somehow, it doesn't detect me as if I was on the same network location as my Linux machine. The thing is, since the Linux machine is hooked up to the internal network, there are no issues on that side. However, some software we use is Windows specific.

My question is, would rerouting the IP address on the KVM solve my issue as to make it seem to be on the same network (authentication internally) or is there a better solution?

Thanks,

Juan